# How to use dtype argument in Panda's from_dict (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {1: 'hello'}
```

I want to turn this into a Panda's dataframe (so a dataframe with strings as row values).

**I am looking at:**
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='columns', dtype=???)

If I leave out the "dtype" argument I get:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Using "orient='columns'" means using the keys as columns. But how do I use the dtype then (I assume the error is due to the num/string issue)?

**Answer summarized:**
Construct "d" as:

```
d = {1: ['hello']}
```

Then use:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bracket 'hello' if  passed without the index.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict({1: ['hello']}, orient='columns', dtype=str)
       1
0  hello
```

Note that 'columns' is the default value for orient and is not required.  Also, the dtype will be inferred if not given explicitly.

Comment: Ah! So using "{1: 'hello'}" does not work, it needs to be a list? Hmm (I guess a string is already a list)

Comment: Yes, e.g. "{1: ['hello', 'world']}"